# Does the wall termination vent for a kitchen range hood need fastened to the duct tightly?

Tags: kitchens, ventilation, exhaust-fan

6" duct running out through exterior wall.  For my dryer wall vent, I used a pipe clamp to tightly secure the round duct around the outside of the male fitting on the wall vent.  I have access to this space if I ever need to replace the wall vent.  Once this kitchen is done, I will not have access to the space for the range hood vent.  Looking to the future, in case I ever need to replace the wall vent, do I simply friction fit the male fitting of the wall vent into the range hood duct so that I can easily slide a new one in?

I can't see any way people could replace these in an exterior wall if they secured the duct to the vent with a clamp or tape.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on your scenario (photos would be great), but range hood vent flanges are almost never clamped or otherwise fastened to the duct. They basically tilt into place against or inside the duct.

Comment: I think that is the issue.  Being in the attic, I insulated my dryer duct and after securing it to the vent flange with a pipe clamp.  If I ever need to replace it, it is accessible.  So typically, the vent flange on a wall vent just slips into the duct.  This is what I was looking for.  Warm air leakage into the cold wall is not a concern or is the friction fit tight enough to eliminate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ducts do not need to be securely fastened to their wall vent counterparts, nor taped.  Simply pushing the duct over the male fitting of the wall vent will suffice.